# Error install ldap for php 5.3 on CentOS 5.5

Tags: php, ldap, centos

Error install `ldap` for `PHP 5.3` on `CentOS 5.5`

Error message as below :

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install php-ldap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-ldap.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-ldap
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-ldap-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-ldap-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-ldap-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Comment: Try to format better the output. Also, have you tried the suggestion? And also, in my little experience with CentOS, sometimes `yum clean all` also does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install `yum install php-common` first

Comment: I tried yum install php-common.but system message show already installed.

Comment: ty  `rpm -qa | grep php` to see which version is installed. maybe a yum update all helps

Comment: php-common install successful but yum install php-ldap still error.

Comment: php-5.3.6-1.w5
php-common-5.3.6-1.w5
php-pdo-5.3.6-1.w5
php-odbc-5.3.6-1.w5
php-cli-5.3.6-1.w5
php-mysql-5.3.6-1.w5
php-devel-5.3.6-1.w5

Comment: as your error sais, php-comon is required in version `php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3` `5.1.6-27` you have currently install version `5.3.6-1` which would be a massive downgrade.. did you tried to install `php53-ldap` instead?

Comment: Yes i am tired to install php53-ldap ?Please tell me solution

Answer (score 1):

install `yum install php53-ldap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

or try install yum install php55w-ldap instead.